# database index check before inserting vs unique index

Tags: php, sql

I have a usergroups(many-to-many relationship) and I have a dilemma. I can check if user is already in group which will take 2 queries to a database(check and insert), or I can put a unique index on user_id and group_id and simply try to insert new row which will result in correct usergroups anyway(would fail if user has such group).

Question: Which method would be have faster performance on really big application with millions of rows in such table?

PS. I'm aware that second method might fail due to other reasons than unique constraint, and it might seem as a bad practice for some people.

Comment: If the first method is concrete and the second "might fail" then performance isn't the issue...

Comment: it would fail in any situation(only in first situation it would fail for something else than constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for the first method to perform well, you would need an index, so I think an unique index is going to be necessary.

For performance, doing the second approach is going to be better as when you do the insert, it's going to check again for uniqueness if you have an index in place.

I would do the second approach, and just have the required exception handling in place.